# display points with lat longs in map and popup the values for a point

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have latitudes, longitudes and related weather data in Excel or CSV format.

I need to develop an application in JSP to display weather data like rainfall in map (I have a shape file for particular map) through GPS points (latitudes and longitudes). When I'd click the point it'd pop up the given values in a small pop window.

I would need some guidance about how to start developing the application.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have code samples to research

[Code Samples](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples)

All of the examples contained in the Maps JavaScript API documentation set are listed below for quick reference.